# Can't get a function to return a value [Solved]

Tags: c, function

I need to get the largest and the smallest number out of three using two functions. I assigned the inputted numbers to the function parameters and wrote the functions but I don't seem to be getting the value returned from the function. Code compiles and prints correctly but instead of the smallest and largest number, I am getting a bunch of zeroes.

**Edit:
When assigning the value to a variable, the variable needs to be written first. For example first = number is not the same as number = first.**

**Also, my way of checking which number is the largest/smallest is not done correctly here :D**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int smallest(int first, int second, int third);
int largest(int first, int second, int third);

int main()
{
    int first_number, second_number, third_number, largest_number, smallest_number;
    
    printf("Enter the 1. number:");
    scanf("%d", &first_number);
    printf("Enter the 2. number:");
    scanf("%d", &second_number);
    printf("Enter the 3. number:");
    scanf("%d", &third_number);
    
    largest_number = largest(first_number, second_number, third_number);
    smallest_number = smallest(first_number, second_number, third_number);
    
    printf("Among the numbers you entered,\nthe largest was %d and the smallest was %d.", largest_number, smallest_number);
    
    return 0;
}

int largest(int first, int second, int third)
{
    int number;
    
    if (first>second && second>third)
        first = number;
    else if (second>third && third>first)
        second = number;
    else
        third = number;
    return number;
}

int smallest(int first, int second, int third)
{
    int number;
    
    if (first<second && second<third) 
        first = number; 
    else if (second<third && third<first) 
        second = number; 
    else 
        third = number; 
    
    return number;
}
```

Comment: Note that e.g. `third = number` is *not* the same as `number = third`. I'll guess it's the second version you want, where you assign *to* `number`?

Comment: Please don't write "solved" or some such, instead if an answer solved the problem then mark it as such (click the "tick" for the answer).

Answer (score 0):

You give the value of the first to number and you test with the following ones to give it their values if any.

```
int largest(int first, int second, int third)
{
    int number = first;
    if (second>number) number=second;
    if (third>number) number=third;

    return number;
}

int smallest(int first, int second, int third)
{
    int number = first;
    if (second<number) number=second;
    if (third<number) number=third;

    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int largest(int first, int second, int third)
> {
>     int number;
>
>     if (first>second && second>third)
>         first = number;
>     else if (second>third && third>first)
>         second = number;
>     else
>         third = number;
>     return number;
> }
> ```

The problem is here: `first = number` assigns the value of `number` to the variable `first`. So when you return the value of number, you return the value of an uninitialized variable.

You should replace `something = number` by `number = something` in your `largest()` and `smallest()` functions.

By the way, your conditions won't work, even with the fix I suggested:

```
if (first>second && second>third)
        number = first;
```

Here, if `first == 8`, `second == 4` and `third == 6`, this condition will fail to assign the value of `first` to `number`, but I'll let you figure out why on your own.